# Perform hourly logrotate on JBoss EAP 7 access log

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-7

By default, JBoss EAP 7 rotates its access log daily.
I needed to set this to like, HOURLY.

**Reason**:

- We have a script that automatically downloads the *rotated* access log file.
- But doing this ^  would greatly increase CPU usage (because the access log at the end of the day is VERY large, and our system's performance is unfortunately reduced while downloading it)

What I know is that, in the **standalone.xml**, I've tried adding the one below to make the JBoss *server* log to rotate every hour.

```
    <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd-HH"/>
```

But this method does not apply to access log (because its settings is weirdly placed in a different part of the standalone.xml)

I've tried experimenting with the `access-log` tags to have any of the following. But it just throws an error.

1. `<access-log suffix=".yyyy-MM-dd-HH" ...`
2. `<access-log rotate="hourly" ...`

...and i can't seem to find a VERY detailed guide about **standalone.xml** of JBoss EAP 7. I'm thinking that I should use a tag value for the `access-log` part.

Please help. Does anyone know of a way to do this? :(

System specs

- Oracle Linux 6.9
- JBoss EAP 7

Thanks and best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:3.0">
    ...(snip)...
    <!-- size-based log rotation -->
    <size-rotating-file-handler name="access-log" autoflush="true">
        <formatter>
            <named-formatter name="access-log-formatter"/>
        </formatter>
        <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="access.log"/>
        <rotate-size value="10m"/>
        <max-backup-index value="10"/>
        <append value="true"/>
    </size-rotating-file-handler>
    <! -- or custom interval (hourly) log rotation
    <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="access-log-custom" autoflush="true">
        <formatter>
            <named-formatter name="access-log-formatter"/>
        </formatter>
        <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="access.log"/>
        <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd-HH"/>
        <append value="true"/>
    </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
    --->
    ...(snip)...
    <logger category="io.undertow.accesslog" use-parent-handlers="false">
        <handlers>
            <handler name="access-log"/>
        </handlers>
    </logger>
    ...(snip)...
    <formatter name="access-log-formatter">
        <pattern-formatter pattern="%s%n"/>
    </formatter>
</subsystem>

...(snip)...

<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:3.1" statistics-enabled="true">
    ...(snip)...
    <server name="default-server">
        <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" record-request-start-time="true"/>
        <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
            ...(snip)...
            <access-log use-server-log="true" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b &quot;%{i,Referer}&quot; &quot;%{i,User-Agent}&quot; &quot;%{i,COOKIE}&quot; &quot;%{o,SET-COOKIE}&quot; %S &quot;%I&quot; %T"/>
            ...(snip)...
        </host>
    </server>
    ...(snip)...
</subsystem>
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea! Although currently I'm not yet able to test this in our environment (because its still being used by other developers).

Comment: Just a little question: does this part `<access-log use-server-log...` means that the stuff that goes to the access log will now go to the server log file instead? Because we prefer to have server log and access log to be different files though.